# ValueError at /profile/ ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: python, html, django

I'm learning Django in Python and have been following a tutorial. I'm trying to get an area to edit the users profile information but I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError at /profile/
ModelForm has no model class specified.
```

This is my forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
from django.forms import ModelForm


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']



class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form' : form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    u_form = UserUpdateForm()
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm()

    context = {
        'u_form' : u_form,
        'p_form' : p_form
    
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `UserUpdateForm`, you need to specify the `model` and `fields` in a `Meta` inner class:

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```